# Highcharts minPointLength on columnrange not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with the columnrange chart type, and some of my could end up being much much smaller than the normal size, so I would like to specify the minPointLength so that the small data points are still visible amidst their larger neighbors and can easily be hovered over and clicked on. I have tried placing the minPointLength option in multiple places throughout my code, but it doesn't seem to ever affect the size of the columns. I have gotten minPointLength to work fine on other chart types, but not with the columnrange chart. Here is a little js fiddle I borrowed and modified to attempt to accomplish what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/kdCgU/7/

```
$(function() {

window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            minPointLength: 10, //This doesn't seem to do anything
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,

            },
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: "Product A",
        data: [[-200, 200]]},
    {
        name: "Product B",
        data: [[-150, 150]]},
    {
        name: "Product C",
        data: [[-100, 100]]},
    {   name: "Small Data",
        data: [[0, 1]]}
                         ]
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems that is a bug. I can make it work either here. Maybe you should report it on their website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known bug reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1448) , but is fixed in `master branch`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/kdCgU/8/

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment it is a bug. It is already reported on their github [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1448).

It seems to be fixed on the `master` :

http://jsfiddle.net/xAU6X/